# Workflow dynamically pulling data from InfoPath form control fields

Tags: infopath, infopath2010

When a user fills out my form, they're to choose who their manager and advisor is from a dropdown list. At the end of the form, two textfields are autopopulated with that same manager and advisor. When the form is submitted, the specified manager and advisor are to be notified in succession to open the form and choose an approval status (Pending, Approved, Rejected), and re-save the form.

What I'm trying to achieve: I'd like the workflow to pull the specified manager and advisor and use that information within the workflow. Is there a way to dynamically have the workflow interact with form field values?

EDIT: 
I'm using Visio to first graphically design my workflow, then I was going to add the logic to it once imported to SharePoint designer. So, firstly, shouldn't I need to add the correct Workflow symbols together within Visio? If so, which symbols do I need to grab the user-selected approver from the form field?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is - you can just publish the InfoPath form fields to your SharePoint library, then the values of the fields would be available for your workflow:
[image]

Of course you will still need to code some logic to convert your text-based field to a real user who can be notified.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Can you please elaborate on how I can specifically publish form _fields_ so they can be available in my workflow? I thought you publish a form as a whole and attach a workflow to that form.  Can you also describe what sort of logic I should add to convert my text-based field to a real user to be notified? That would be suppperr helpful. Thank you.

Comment: For example, I'm using Visio to first graphically design my workflow, then I was going to add the logic to it once imported to SharePoint designer. So, firstly, shouldn't I need to add the correct Workflow symbols together within Visio?

Comment: you might want to start straight ahead with SharePoint Designer, as the Visio workflows are usually power-user (high-level) only like x0n said.

Comment: Lot's of questions in here... You should read up on some tutorials first. Visio is simply a graphical representation **without any** logic (besides a couple of IF-THEN). All the "meat" of the workflow is being done in SharePoint Designer. Your original question was about InfoPath forms though - with these you have the possibility to publish form fields to a SP list. If your question is about Workflows, you can create workflow fields as well which will appear in your list. About logic converting text to real user --> better use a People Picker control, not dropdown boxes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure Visio doesn't support those kind of workflow operations. It's more about designing a high-level workflow. Download sharepoint designer 2010 - it's free, and it is a far more powerful tool for designing workflows and it will let you do what @moontear suggests.

**Microsoft SharePoint Designer 2010 (32-bit)**

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=16573